# Force dependence on velocity : Drag

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, drag

I just listened to the second lecture of Leonard Susskind on classical mechanics where he discussed that force can't be proportional to velocity, since it's unable to retro-dict (predict past).  He used the example of an oscillator to do this.  But we know that drag, which is a type of force, is proportional to velocity squared ($v^{2}$).  Does this go against the basic laws of physics (since it makes us unable to retro-dict)?

Comment: Could you explain your and Susskind's reasoning in more detail, for those of us who haven't listened to his lecture?

Comment: There is neither a requirement that nature has to allow us to reconstruct the past, nor does it actually allow us to do so in quantum mechanics. That there can't be first order forces in Hamiltonian mechanics, at least not in a way that would agree with observations, is, among other things a consequence of energy conservation. Forces proportional to the square of the velocity do not change this problem, by the way.

Comment: For a physicist (as compared with an engineer) drag isn't "a type of force". If you make a model of the system which includes some version of kinetic theory of the solid or fluid, "drag" simply converts macroscopic "kinetic energy" of a body ($mv^2/2$) into "internal heat energy" - i.e. it destroys the *correlation* between the velocities of each individual particle in the system. But that is outside the scope of  the spherical cow called "introduction to classical mechanics". Engineers usually take the more pragmatic "duck typing" view that if something acts like a force, then it's a force.

Answer (score 1):

I only watched the video to the point (about 15 min after the start) where Susskind he explained that according to Aristotle's "law of motion", the mass in a spring-and-mass system would move towards its equilibrium position with an exponentially decreasing velocity. Therefore, if you observe the mass when it is close to its equilibrium position and not moving to within the accuracy of your measurements, you have no way to accurately predict its past motion.

I hope I didn't miss something relevant to the OP's question later in the video!

Of course you also can't always predict the past motion of real-world macroscopic objects where *Newtonian* mechanics is a perfectly adequate mathematical description of their behaviour. If you observe a rock lying motionless (to within your observational error) at the bottom of a steep cliff face, there is no way that Newtonian mechanics can tell you exactly where it fell from or when it fell.

As an argument for why "Aristotle's law of motion must be wrong", Susskind's reasoning seems deeply flawed. For example, consider Fourier's law of heat conduction. If an object is thermally insulated from its surroundings and has an initial non-uniform temperature distribution, the temperature at each point will change exponentially and approach the equilibrium state of a uniform temperature distribution, analogous to Susskind's analysis of "Aristotle's law". If you observe the object has a uniform temperature, you can't predict the past history of its temperature, for exactly the same reason as in Susskind's analysis. But I doubt whether Susskind would claim that Fourier's law of heat conduction, which is *consistent* with experimental observations of the temperature changes, is therefore "wrong" because it can't predict the past.

Worse than that, towards the end of the 19th century it was discovered that there are system obeying Newton's laws of motion where you can't even predict the *future* behaviour of a system accurately, unless you know its current configuration of the system to an "infinite" precision. That discovery was the starting point for the study of chaotic dynamics by Lyapunov, Poincaré, etc.

Indeed, you can't accurately predict *everything* about the future motion of systems that nobody would consider "chaotic", unless you know the exact mechanical properties of the system. Consider a mass $m$ and a spring $k$ performing undamped simple harmonic motion. If the mass is at its maximum displacement $a$ at time $0$, its displacement at other times is given by $a \cos \omega t$ where $\omega^2 = k/m$.

That looks simple enough, but suppose you don't know $m$ and $k$ *exactly*, and the physical frequency of oscillation is $\omega' = \omega(1 + \epsilon)$. At some future time, you may find $\cos \omega t = 1$ but $\cos \omega' t = -1$, i.e. you predict the mass is at position $+a$ from equilibrium, but it is actually at $-a$. I wonder what Susskind's response to that "prediction failure" would be.